# Is there a way to declare method that takes any lambda as parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to write a method in C# that will accept lambda of any type, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I'm developing a class that will process text commands. I want to implement it in such a way that arguments will be automatically determined from lambda expression that handles particular command.

Here is an example of what API I would like to get:

```cs
commandProcessor.AddCommand("setpos", (int x, int y)=>{
    //do stuff
});
commandProcessor.AddCommand("changename",(string newName)=>{
    //do completely different stuff
});
```

And my command processor will look like this:

```
Dictionary<string, MagicType> mCommands;

public void AddCommand(string commandName, MagicType commandHandler){
    mCommands[commandName] = commandHandler;
}
```

Is there a MagicType that I can use or maybe I should use a completely different approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need this kind of functionality you can do something like this.

```
public delegate object GenericCommand (params object[] parameters);
```

Then you would need to provide an overload to every method you want to store that's compliant with GenericCommand's definition.

Here is an example of what this would look like.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public delegate object GenericCommand (params object[] parameters);

    public static object Function1 (params object[] parameters) => Function1 ((int)parameters[0], (int)parameters[1]);
    public static int Function1 (int i, int j) => (i + j);

    private static Dictionary<string, GenericCommand> commands;

    public static void Main()
    {
        commands = new Dictionary<string, GenericCommand> ();

        commands.Add ("Function1", Function1);

        int i = (int)commands["Function1"](1, 2);

        Console.WriteLine (i); // 3
    }   
}
```

---

All that being said, there's a reason why this is kind of tricky to do in a language like C#. In strongly-typed languages, the expectation is that when a method is called, the user has a specific set of inputs in mind and is expecting to get a specific type of output back. There's usually little need for something as nondescript as `GenericCommand` because if you know the method's name and where it normally lives why not just call it directly?

If you find yourself needing this kind of functionality a lot in your program, then I would consider maybe writing that part of your baseline in another language. My knowledge of it is limited, but I believe [F#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/what-is-fsharp) can do what you're asking without nearly as much hassle. Javascript is another option, but F# was written as a sister functional language to C# so it might be easier to integrate into your project. Functional languages (as I understand it) care more about the pure functionality of what you're writing than the nature of the operands, though I'm not so sure it's as agnostic about the number of arguments. It certainly warrants looking into.

Comment: In the end I decided to use a different approach. This answer gave me some interesting thoughts to ponder.

Answer (score 3):

Except when compiling to `Expression`s, lambdas are compiled to instances of `System.Delegate`. But that's a very vague type for which you would have to use reflection to discover anything.

You might do better by declaring a set of overloads accepting `Action`, `Action<T>`, `Action<T1, T2>`, etc. These are the BCL's built-in delegate types for functions that return `void`.

Comment: _"All lambdas are delegates"_ -- that's not really true. A lambda is a lambda. Depending on context, it may be compiled into a delegate instantiation, or into an expression. The latter is _not_ a delegate.

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes I forgot about lambdas assigning to `Expression` types. Will update.